# How to create a dynamic LOV at runtime

Tags: dynamic, oracle-adf, lov

How to create a dynamic attribute in lov at runtime?
Suppose I have a employee lov, where only two attributes are currently present like employee id and employee name.

It user want to add a few more column at run time like employee age and employee salary.
Without changing the LOV logic. The user has one master table where IT user can handle how many attribute should be displayed to business user. They can add a new parameter in table which can be displayed.

Can anybody suggest me some approach to handle this type of scenario?

Comment: Are you using ADF BC as a model ? If yes do you have a view object for this LOV ?

Comment: Yes .I am using adf bc and view object

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, I'd use backingBean with method that returns `List`, that implemented as `ArrayList<SelectItem>`. Then populate from any source(like VO, or whatever mixed) `label` and `value` according to your current user request.